# undefined method `date_field' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails v4.0.0 and I'm trying to create a form with date type

here's the form

```
<%= form_for(@booking, remote: true) do |b| %>

    <header>
        <h1>Edit booking</h1>
    </header>

    <%= p.date_field :check_in,  placeholder: "Check-in" %>
    <%= p.date_field :check_out, placeholder: "Check-out" %>
    <%= p.number_field :units, placeholder: "Units" %>
    <%= p.submit "Save" %> 

<% end %>
```

but I get an

```
undefined method `date_field' for nil:NilClass
```

any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: `b` (`do |b|`) versus `p` (`p.date_field`). These should be the same, so you'll have to decide which name to keep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the form for you say the builder is `b`:

```
form_for(@booking, remote: true) do |b|
```

But when you use it you say it's `p`:

```
p.submit "Save"
```

And given it's a form builder, I'd rather have it called `f`.